# How can I get the GCE instance name where my script is running?

Tags: google-compute-engine, gcutil

I'm currently trying to manipulate the metadata of my instance from the startup-script. To do that I have to use the following command :

```
gcutil setinstancemetadata <instance-name> --metadata=<key-1:value-1> --fingerprint=<current-fingerprint-hash>
```

As you can see the command ask for the *instance-name*. For I tried to get it from the metadata, but it was not there (see : [Default Metadata](https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/metadata#default)).

My question is how to get this instance name ?

**Edit:** For now my only solution is to add the instance-name as a metadata when I create the instance :

```
gcutil addintance my-cool-instance --metadata=instance-name:my-cool-instance
```

And then get it with a curl request :

```
curl 'http://metadata/computeMetadata/v1/instance/attributes/instance-name' -H "X-Google-Metadata-Request: True"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The instance name is the same as its hostname, you can just use the $HOSTNAME environmental variable, e.g.:

```
gcutil setinstancemetadata $HOSTNAME --metadata=<key-1:value-1> --fingerprint=<current-fingerprint-hash>
```

This works on my instance which was built from the debian-7-wheezy-v20140318 image.

UPDATE: The above works fine on Debian 7 (Wheezy), but on OS's where the HOSTNAME variable is the fully qualified domain name, rather than just the host name, you should use the syntax below:

```
gcutil setinstancemetadata $($HOSTNAME | cut -d . -f1) --metadata=<key-1:value-1> --fingerprint=<current-fingerprint-hash>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. On CentOS, the hostname seems a little bit different : `my-cool-instance.c.my-cool-project.xxxx.com.yyyyy`. I just add a `cut` and it is solved.

Comment: Not all the time the instance name is same as the hostname. What if you have a custom hostname? The name of the instance is different from the hostname in that case.

Answer (score 4):

Google Cloud Platform MetaData URL supports getting the instance name via `hostname` resource, irrespective of any custom hostnames set for the instance. That's why `$HOSTNAME` is not recommended.

**URL1:**

```
INSTANCE_NAME=$(curl http://169.254.169.254/0.1/meta-data/hostname -s | cut -d "." -f1)
```

**URL2:**

```
INSTANCE_NAME=$(curl http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/hostname -H Metadata-Flavor:Google | cut -d . -f1)
```

GCP follows a common regex pattern for the resource names `(?:[a-z](?:[-a-z0-9]{0,61}[a-z0-9])?)` , so it's safe to cut the result based on `.` and use the first part as the instance name.

Answer (score 0):

A better means to get the instance name is to use the `hostname` command included in the GCE images :

```
[benoit@my-instance ~]$ hostname
my-instance
```

Comment: This doesn't get the full gce hostname which usually includes the project name.